# Prisma ORM returns domain logic error: `Conversion from Uuid() to INT failed` on findMany()

Tags: prisma

#### Question

Why am I receiving the following error when I visit the endpoint  /users, and what are possible fix routes?

```
[1]   19 const usersRouter = express_1.default.Router();
[1]   20 usersRouter.get("/", (req, res) => __awaiter(void 0, void 0, void 0, function* () {
[1]   21     try {
[1] → 22         const allUsers = yield prisma.user.findMany(
[1] Error in domain logic: Conversion from `Uuid(ac44955b-ea51-474a-ae89-5a6e1744df9a)` to `Int` failed.
[1]     at Cn.handleRequestError (~\backend\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:123:6989)
[1]     at Cn.handleAndLogRequestError (~\backend\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:123:6206)
[1]     at Cn.request (~\backend\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:123:5926)
[1]     at async l (~\backend\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:128:9968)
```

#### Expected Behavior

Whenever I visit the endpoint /users, I should be responded with a JSON of all of our users.

```
[
  {
    "userid": "d536eb96-02d5-4a7b-8b72-90c1585db30d",
    "user_name": "mockuser1",
    "user_abbreviation": "mu1
  },
  {
    "userid": "35c709e3-b498-4493-856b-f46b8df370a1",
    "user_name": "mockuser2",
    "user_abbreviation": "mu2
  },
 {
    "userid": "99718d23-bd15-446a-aef7-bb71c844bec5",
    "user_name": "mockuser3",
    "user_abbreviation": "mu3
  },
]
```

#### How to reproduce

Background information:

Backend Technologies in use: [Node, Express, Typescript, Prisma, Postgres]

I'm running a postgres database which uses UUID strings as primary keys for each table. The database was formerly built out (seeded) in postgres.

Used `npx prisma db pull` to successfully create a prisma schema .

Currently, expressJS is setup to run prisma commands and perform CRUD functionalities.

```
import express from "express";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import { busyHandler, catchHandler, handleError } from "../../common/common.error";
const prisma = new PrismaClient();
const usersRouter = express.Router();

usersRouter.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const allUsers = await prisma.user.findMany();
        res.send(allUsers);
    } catch (err) {
        catchHandler(res, err);
    } finally {
        await prisma.$disconnect();
    }
});
```

#### What I've tried

I've also tried the following:

- replacing the respond method in the try-catch to res.json(allUsers):

```
usersRouter.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const allUsers = await prisma.user.findMany();
        res.json(allUsers);
    } catch (err) {
        catchHandler(res, err);
    } finally {
        await prisma.$disconnect();
    }
});
```

- filtering the findMany:

```
usersRouter.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await prisma.user.findMany(where:{userid:'ac44955b-ea51-474a-ae89-5a6e1744df9a');
        res.send(user);
    } catch (err) {
        catchHandler(res, err);
    } finally {
        await prisma.$disconnect();
    }
});
```

#### Information about Prisma Schema, Client Queries and Environment

```
model user {
  userid                       String           @id @db.Uuid
  user_name              String?
  user_abbreviation      String?
}
```

```
usersRouter.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const allUsers = await prisma.user.findMany();
        res.send(allUsers);
    } catch (err) {
        catchHandler(res, err);
    } finally {
        await prisma.$disconnect();
    }
});
```

- OS: Windows
- Database: PostgreSQL
- Node.js version: v16.14.2
- RestAPI: Expressjs
- Language: Typescript
- prisma version: 5.3.1
- @prisma/client version: 5.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Answered on Prisma GitHub @ludralph:

> The error message you're seeing suggests that somewhere in your
> application or database, a UUID is being incorrectly treated as an
> Int. However, from the code and schema you've provided, it's not clear
> where this could be happening. The error could be coming from another
> part of your application that's not shown in the code you've provided.
> Check any other code that interacts with the user table and ensure
> it's treating userid as a String.